# Angular dependent components

Tags: angular

I have three components.

- CategoryComponent - list of categories
- ListComponent - list of elements of selected category
- ScreenComponent - composition of MenuComponent and ContentComponent

The ScreenComponent template looks like:

```
<category-list></category-list>
<elements-list [categoryId]="6"></elements-list>
```

I want ListComponent to get ID of category selected in CategoryComponent instead of hardcoded `6`. How can I do this? Is this correct approach or the CategoryComponent job should be done by ScreenComponent?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no relation (parent / child) between these two components, you need to leverage a shared service. The elements list would register to an observable into the service to be notified when a category is selected and update itself accordingly.

This service could contain both data and observables to subscribe on to be notified when data are updated.

- **Service**

  ```
  export class SharedService {
    observable: Observable<any>;
    observer: Observer<any>;

    constructor() {
      this.observable = new Observable.create(observer => {
        this.observer = observer;
      }).share();

    updateData() {
      this.observer.next('something');
    }
  }
  ```
- **Component**

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-component1',
    template: `
      (...)
    `
  })
  export class MyComponent1 {
    constructor(private service:ListService) {
      this.service.observable.subscribe.(data => {
        (...)
      });
    }
  }
  ```
- **bootstrap**

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
  ```

See this question for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924)
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)